# reading data of columns and rows from text files in dev c++

Tags: c++

I wrote this piece of code which reads data from text file `StudentRec.txt` which contains data in different rows and columns and displays it. The program compiles well but does not execute properly.

```
ifstream infile; 
infile.open("StudentRec.txt"); 

int rows(0); 
int columns(0);   

string lname[rows][columns]; 
int id[rows][columns]; 
int Age[rows][columns]; 
double gpa[rows][columns]; 

infile>>rows>>columns;
infile>>rows>>columns;  

for(int i=0;i<6;i++) 
{ 
  for(int j=0;j<4;j++) 
  { 
   infile>>lname[i][j]>> id[i][j]>> Age[i][j]>> gpa[i][j];
   cout<<lname[i][j]<<"\t"<<id[i][j]<<"\t"<<Age[i][j]<<"\t"<<gpa[i][j]<<endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not execute properly"? Does it crash? Show wrong result? Something else? Can you please elaborate? And can you please show the contents of the input file? And also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),.

Comment: well.. it does crash

Comment: Why are you reading into `rows` and `columns` twice?

Answer (score 2):

While you are thinking about my comment, and how you can improve your question, the actual problem is these lines:

```
int rows(0); 
int columns(0);   

string lname[rows][columns]; 
int id[rows][columns]; 
int Age[rows][columns]; 
double gpa[rows][columns];
```

First of all C++ does not have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) though some compilers allow it as an extension. But the real problem is that you are creating arrays of size *zero*. All indexing will be out of bounds, and lead to *undefined behavior*.

If the compiler allows variable-length arrays, move the definition of the arrays to *after* you read the sizes into `rows` and `columns`.